# SQL - Convert INT to Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert INT (YYYYMM) value to DATE.

I have read articles which mention that converts from char to date format. So I am curious to know - which of the foll. is a good approach?

Example:

```
DECLARE @PERIOD INT ='201806'

SELECT CAST(CONCAT(@Period,'01') AS DATE) SQLCAST1
,CAST(CAST(@Period AS varchar(6))+'01'  AS DATE) SQLCAST2
```

Which is the ideal approach and why? Do we have other better approach?

Answer (score 5):

I am not a fan of implicit data type conversions, so I would phrase the first as:

```
select convert(date, convert(varchar(6),  @PERIOD ) + '01')
```

Or use `datefromparts()` which is a built-in function for constructing dates:

```
select datefromparts( @PERIOD / 100,  @PERIOD % 100, 1)
```

Comment: @Lucky . . . I would speculate that that integer math and one function call is faster than two conversions and a string aggregation.  However, the difference should be negligible in a large query.

Comment: @Lucky, the OP also asked if there is a better approach.  I, personally, like Gordon's `DateFromParts()` approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method, First you have to convert to char then convert to date time,

```
    declare @intValue int
    select @intValue = 201907
   select convert(date, convert(varchar(6),  @intValue ) + '01')
```

Comment: This wasn't OPs question; he didn't have the day part in his INT.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently concat is the most efficient method.

https://raresql.com/2013/03/12/sql-server-string-concatenation-faster-method/

Cast also appears to be the most efficient method for parsing a standard date string (see the try_cast times for DateTime)

[SQL - Convert INT to Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56934412/sql-convert-int-to-date/56934569#56934569)

Your first method is most efficient.

Comment: The article you linked about concatenation's performance doesn't address date conversion.  It's about three different approaches to turning three string columns which might contain `Null` into a single value.  We're starting with an `Int` here, so using string concatenation requires converting the `Int` to a `VarChar` first.